# Different Facebook comment box after each ajax call

Tags: ajax, facebook-comments

my problem is this:
I've got a webpage that changes each time the user clicks the button. The title is updated, a graph. Seeing as the page now has different content, I would love to have a different commenting section. However, the url is exactly the same (because all of the content is ajax loaded) and so I'm wondering whether it is possible to have a new FB comment box be generated as well (it would need to be generated because there are hundreds of sets of content that the user can click through)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is possible to generate a new comment box.

After the AJAX call, you will need to remove the old comments box from the DOM, then insert a new one into the DOM and then call the javascript function `FB.XFBML.parse();` to get Facebook to rerender it.

Comment: This is good news! but how would I go about creating the new one? The code for the comments is: `<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://mywebsite.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>` - so how could I alter this (after each ajax call) so that it is a different comment box?

Comment: `$("#fbCommentsPlaceholder").html('<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://mywebsite.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>');FB.XFBML.parse();`

Comment: Also note that when the comment box itself is parsed as a result of the `XMLHttpRequest`, you will only need to call `FB.XFBML.parse()` when the parsing is finished.

Answer (score 0):

I found a faster way to change the comments, just changing the href:

```
    $(".fb-comments").attr('data-href', data_href);
    FB.XFBML.parse();
```