# Auto-generated facebook comments boxes

Tags: html, facebook-comments

I´m implementing facebook comments boxes on my news pages. And it works. The problem is that if I make a comment on one page, it will display on ALL pages which contains fb comment boxes.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
<b><div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://selandia-ceu.dk/selandia/nyheder.aspx" data-num-posts="3" data-width="500"></div>

<script>
  var fb-comments = document.getElementById('fb-comments');  
  mydiv.innerHTML =
    '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="' + document.location.href + '" data-num-posts="3" data-width="500"></fb:comments>';  
  FB.XFBML.parse(fb-comments);
</script></b>
```

The website is using Microsoft Server. The url in the code is supposed to refer to the current page one is viewing. Anyone know what I´m supposed to do? :)

The comments are temporary disabled on the pages.

I got the extra bit of code (FB.XFBML.parse) from this thread:
[Different Facebook comment box after each ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911425/different-facebook-comment-box-after-each-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to clean up your Open Graph tags, as the URL that each comments plugin is pointed to will be scraped by the Open Graph linter and used to determine the canonical URL. The problem is likely that your comments plugins all end up pointing to the same canonical URL:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fselandia-ceu.dk%2Fselandia%2Fnyheder.aspx

Use this Debug tool to inspect your Open Graph tags and ensure each page has it's own canonical URL. You also need to correct the fb:admins tag that you have in your HTML as suggested by the debugger.